# Android preferences not being effected in app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm an Android newbie. 
I'm writing an app, which depends on a user inputted URL for it to work. I have code in my main activity which detects if the user preference has been set. If not, it opens an edit preference activity.

However, my app has to crash at least once or twice before it "registers" my new pref settings. How can I correct this?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // integrate our shared preferences settings
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefix = sharedPrefs.getString("manual_fetch_domain", "");

    if (prefix.length() < 7) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditSettingsActivity.class));
    }
}

public void onPrimaryClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            PrimaryImageGridActivity.class);

    //confirm our settings
    if (prefix.length() < 7) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditSettingsActivity.class));
    }

    String readTwitterFeed = readTwitterFeed(prefix + Constants.SERVER_URL);
    List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>();
    int k = 0;

    if (readTwitterFeed != null) {
        //code here
    }

}

public String readTwitterFeed(String y) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(y);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content), 16384);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // error check again
    String tmp = builder.toString();
    if (tmp.length() < 2)
        return null;
    else
        return builder.toString();
}
```

Sections of my log cat follow:

```
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 11 more
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.src.shady.MainActivity.readTwitterFeed(MainActivity.java:118)
07-10 13:23:18.818: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.src.shady.MainActivity.onPrimaryImageGridClick(MainActivity.java:67)
```

Comment: Please post the LogCat. Ideally, look at it yourself first - you may be able to see from there where you are going wrong.

Comment: I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException on the line

Comment: readTwitterFeed(prefix + Constants.SERVER_URL); . The prefix is null so the apps reads a malformed URL and raises this exception

Comment: If it is null then something has set "manual_fetch_domain" null. If it is empty then perhaps "manual_fetch_domain" can't be found, because you set the empty string "" in your prefix= statement. I know nothing about Twitter, so I'm out of here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you added `onClick` into *layout.xml* file, but:

- *layout.xml* was set to activity and `onClick` is not declared(handler is absent)
- *layout.xml* was set to dialog(this is wrong, you need to add [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html) to handle actions)